# Getting an error: "Keyword ORDER not expected" when creating an AS400 view

Tags: sql, view, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am using the System i Navigator in order to create a View.
My view is very simple:

```
   SELECT MOMAST.ORDNO, MOMAST.FITEM
   FROM AMFLIBT.MOMAST AS MOMAST
   WHERE MOMAST.FITEM LIKE 'POS-%'
   GROUP BY  MOMAST.ORDNO,MOMAST.FITEM
   ORDER BY MOMAST.FITEM,MOMAST.ORDNO
```

When clicking on OK button to creat the view, I am getting the following error:

> SQL0199] Keyword ORDER not expected. Valid tokens: . Cause . . . . . :   The keyword ORDER was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at keyword ORDER.  The partial list of valid tokens is .

When I remove the ORDER BY statement, the view is being created successfully.

I need to create my view with the ORDER BY statement, how can I achieve this task with no errors?

Comment: `ORDER BY` in a view is only valid when selecting the top *n* rows, or limiting to *n* rows. Otherwise, it is wrong. Use `ORDER BY` when selecting **from** the view.

Comment: SQL tables and views don't have an order; indexes have. You might ask a separate question about your perceived need for ORDER BY so an alternative might be suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A view is a relational table, and the relational model defines a table as a set of rows. Since sets are not ordered - by definition - the rows in a view are not ordered, either. Therefore, an `ORDER BY` clause in the view definition is meaningless. The SQL standard (SQL:2003) does not allow an `ORDER BY` clause in a subselect in a `CREATE VIEW` statement, just as it is not allowed in a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

In your case, I recommend creating the view without the `ORDER BY` statement, and using this statement when selecting from the view (not while creating it).

Comment: I also recommend creating the view without the "Order By" clause